# regex performance issues?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2005

I have code like shown below which is doing regex comparison, I thought of to optimize the code. When I checked with .net profiler it shows 80 % time here spending, and I checked my regex filter whether any backtracking occurs but nothing wrong in that regular expression side. So this is the existing code

```
public class TestFilter : SmoothFilter
   {
     public override bool Apply(Team liveEvent)
          {
                   // Apply each individual piece of the filter using the Match method
                   if ((Filter == null) || (Filter.Length <= 0) || Match(Filter, pl.Instance))
                   {

          }

    private bool Match(string pattern, string inputdata)
    {
        bool vals = Regex.IsMatch(inputdata, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return vals;
    }
}
```

When I googled I saw the link http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/regular-expression-performance-comparisons , mentions best and faster method if you are not taking initial start up time. so I modified my code like shown below. But I moved my systems I don't have any tool to profile, Can any body tell me whether it improve really? this modified code below

```
 static readonly Regex regexForMethod_E = new Regex("pattern", RegexOptions.Compiled);

 private bool Match(string pattern, string inputdata)
 {
     bool vals = regexForMethod_E.IsMatch("inputdata");
     return vals;
}
```

**EDIT**

I still I don't know how to move regex instantiation inside Match() method

Comment: You could write your own simple speed test - for example: http://guyellisrocks.com/coding/speed-improvements-with-compiled-regex/ to compare performance

Comment: Your problem can be depend on your Regex pattern. please add more details about your pattern.

Comment: In that case, why use a regex at all if you're just doing a simple comparison for equality?

Comment: In your first example, method `Match` is returing `retval` which doesn't exist. Did you mean to return `vals`?

Comment: @comecme yes thats the one it is vals

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of the pattern. It wont be slower in any case, it will speed up more with greater complexity of the regex.

Also, your codes are not equivalent. To do so, you need to call:

```
new Regex("pattern", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: i didnt get you can you modify my old code with your comments, i have modifief my question

Comment: i still i dont know how to move regex instantiation inside Match() method

Comment: If you want to instantiate it just once, keep it as a class member. Thats the best performing way, if you use the same pattern multiple times.

Comment: What i am saying is when i moved line static readonly Regex regexForMethod_E = new Regex("pattern", RegexOptions.Compiled); to
inside Match() method it is throwing errors

Comment: If you want a better perfomence,you cant have it inside the method.

Comment: Change this line:
[static readonly Regex regexForMethod_E = new Regex("pattern", RegexOptions.Compiled);]
To this line:
[private readonly Regex regexForMethod_E = new Regex(Filter, RegexOptions.Compiled| RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);]

And your method signature will just be:
[private bool Match(string inputdata)]

Comment: this will not work because Calling side Match() is sending two parameters and receiver side only one

Comment: The caller would just call Match(pl.Instance), the Filter will be already in the regexForMethod_E variable. The only holds if the Filter property does not change ! If the Filter does change, keep your original code or modify the regexForMethod_E every time the Filter changes

Comment: we have 5 filters out of that one is Filter, this code will be harcoded for Filter only, so this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I believe so, yes, but I don't know how much.

Long(er) answer: I think that you're saving yourself and the computation a lot of time: look at how much on-the-fly computation your method needs to do in the first instance. Now look at how much it has to do on the second method - your function only needs one parameter passed, rather than 3; that's a performance gain (albeit small).

The Regex has already been calculated, so all that the program needs to do is check it against your input data, rather than taking all parameters and calculating them on-the-fly.

An even faster method would be this:

```
private bool Match(string inputdata)
{
     return regexForMethod_E.IsMatch("inputdata");
}
```

I know that the change is almost negligible, but imagine this call being made 1000 times. That's 1000 boolean variables you don't actually need!

Comment: Are you really saying that only having 1 parameter to a method will perform better than one with 3? And that creating a variable for the return value causes an improvement in performance?

Comment: @nathanwhite okey, but i couldn't understand the one which you mentioned about the parameters in the function, i mean if my new code is wrong or not efficient, will you modify and post it?

Comment: @Jamiec I'd like to mention I said "I think", and "I believe". I would assume so, but please, if you can prove me wrong, I'd love to learn :)

Comment: @vettori I have posted the function. Again, I know it's small, but let me know what you think!

Comment: @nathanwhite but for Match calling side it is sending two paramters, if i put like you mentioned it will throw compilation errors Error  No overload for method 'Match' takes 2 arguments

Comment: @vettori If this is inside a class, you shouldn't need to send in the Regex, it should be available inside the class. If you look at your function, pattern is never used.

Comment: @nathanwhite i am not getting the context, i have updated question with sending and receiving for Match method which has two arguments,i know instantiation of regex, if we do outside method i mean Match() it will improve but how to manage properly?

Comment: @nathanwhite i still i dont know how to move regex instantiation inside Match() method

Comment: @nathanwhite i have 3 kind of filters like pattern,it is not a single one like pattern i mentioned.so what to do here